# Recover data in PHP POST

Tags: php, json, email, post

I have a small problem with my php server.
I am trying to email data that I recover with the $ POST method.
If I do this, the code works and the mail is sent:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: text/json');
$nom = "";
if( isset($_POST['votre_nom']))
{
    $nom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['votre_nom']);
}
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "!Paswword";
$mail->SetFrom("no-reply@domain.com", "TEST", 0);
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello" . nom . ;
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com", "Person One");
$mail->AddCC('email@gmail.com', 'Person Two');

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
?>
```

but when I add data, it gives me a 500 error, as in the following code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: text/json');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
$nom = "";
$email = "";
if(isset($_POST['votre_nom']) && isset($_POST['votre_email']))
{
    $nom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['votre_nom']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['votre_email']);
}   

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "!Password";
$mail->SetFrom("no-reply@domain.com", "TEST", 0);
$mail->Subject = "TEST";
$mail->Body = "Prénom/Nom : " . $nom . 
              "</br>Email : " . $email .;
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com", "Person One");
$mail->AddCC('email@gmail.com', 'Person Two');

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
```

?>

I do not understand where the error may come from, because when I check my JSON everything is there..

If anyone could give me a track to find the solution please :)

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your webserver? Such as the Apache error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is at the level of the following line:

```
"</br>Email : " . $email .;
```

It must be done as follows:

```
"</br>Email : " . $email . "";
```

Comment: Yeah ! Nice ! Thank you :)